# Refer to another section in C# XML documentation comments

Tags: c#, xml-comments, cross-reference

Does anyone know whether it is possible to refer to another section from the text of another one, e.g. to the ‘returns’ section from the ‘summary’ section or vice versa (within the documentation of a given method) and have a hyperlink generated by the compiler? (My original problem was how to refer to the return value from within the ‘summary’, as is already possible for parameters with ‘paramref’ or other members/classes etc. with ‘cref’. Then I realised that this problem is just a special case of the more general one described in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility. Only paramref and typeref.

Maybe you need your own xml comments processor with custom tags. Or try to search about extensibility with custom tags using other tools.

For example NDoc (or maybe sandcastle has also extensibility points, but anyway for sandcastle source code is open):

http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/usersguide.html

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you for clarifying this.